# Combination/Permutation understanding check

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I have a (fairly) simple combination and permutation question, but I'm prone to silly errors and I want to make sure this looks good! I'm a little stuck on D) so direction would be nice :)

Given an alphabet of 13 uppercase letters (N-Z), how many 7 letter strings are there if:

A) No letters can be repeated? Permute(13,7) = 8,648,640

B) Letters can be repeated? $13^7$ = 62,748,517

C) Letter can not be repeated and start with either 'Z' 'U' or 'X'?
Perm(12,6) + Perm(12,6) + Perm(12,6) = 665,280

D) Letters can be repeated and at least on one the following conditions is true.
(i) String starts with Z (ii)fourth letter is U (iii)String ends with x
P(12,6) + P(12,6) + P(12,6) - the overlap of the three (but how?!)

Comment: For A, you also need to count permutations.  For C, again, you need to count permutations.

Comment: By count permutations what do you mean? P(13,7) is my permutation

Comment: Sorry, thought that P(13,7) was your notation for 13 choose 7.

Comment: That would be C(13,7). Good catch though I'll make sure to specifiy!

Comment: For part D, you can break up into 7 cases... Place Z first, don't choose U as fourth, and don't choose X last (there is 1 choice for position 1, 12 choices for position 4, and 12 choices for position 6, you have 13 choices everywhere else). (2) place U in position 4, don't place Z or X in positions 1 and 6,... Then look at pairs i.e. place Z first, and U fourth, don't place X last. Last, Place Z, U and X in their respective positions and put anything in the leftover positions. It's basically inclusion-exclusion principal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A, B and C are correct.

For D, $P(12,6)+P(12,6)+P(12,6)$ is a good start. The problem is that words like Z__U___ are counted twice, so you should subtract those out. Same for Z_____X and ___U__X. So far, we are at
$$
P(12,6)+P(12,6)+P(12,6)-P(11,5)-P(11,5)-P(11,5)
$$
Now, every word has been counted the appropriate number of times except for Z__U__X. Words like this were initially triple counted, but after the first adjustment they were also subtracted out three times, and are no longer counted at all. Therefore, they need to be added back in, for a final answer of
$$
P(12,6)+P(12,6)+P(12,6)-P(11,5)-P(11,5)-P(11,5)+P(10,4)
$$

Comment: Inclusion/Exclusion Principal. Of course!!! Thank you :)